# How can I externalize my environment variables in Angular?

Tags: angular, build, package

We would like to build our Angular app once and deploy it to many environments.  The default build process using the environment files (found in `/src/environments`), bakes one flavor of your environment file (e.g. `/src/environments/environment.prod.ts`) into your main.js file upon compilation.  This means using the normal Angular build patterns will require a separate build per environment as each build package is tied to a specific environment.  This subsequently means that we are in the position of deploying an untested package to our production environment, as our prod build cannot be used in any other environment.

Therefore, we would like to externalize our environment files somehow to allow us to build a single package which can be used in all environments, referencing an external set of properties.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have your configuration be received from the backend would be the simplest thing to do. This really sounds like a bigger underlying problem in the architecture though since you can't properly test on your staging environment.

Comment: You can create an env.js file at root level with all your configurations. Please check this link-https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize the the environment variables by getting them from the Server/API. That's the only way. As explained by @misha130